# Unity Coroutine performances

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I used Coroutine in Unity quite a lot in my projects, they are useful because they allow me to delay functions or do things every X seconds.

Now I know how to use them, but I don't really know what is happening in the background and I am wondering their impact on performances. Are coroutine low/fast ?

For exemple, doing things every few seconds could be done in the Update function, but it can also be done in a coroutine with `WaitForSeconds` or with yield return null. Are they all as efficient as the others ?
I wrote different ways here, which should do the job in theory. But which ones are the best ? If they are all the same, WaitForSeconds seems easier to read and I might prefer it.

**Update way**

```cs
private float shootInterval = 5f;
private float counterDeltaTime = 0f;
private void Update() {
    counterDeltaTime += Time.deltaTime;

    if (counterDeltaTime >= shootInterval) {
        Shoot();
        counterDeltaTime = 0;
    }
}
```

**Coroutine way**

*yield return new WaitForSeconds*

```cs
private void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(ShootEvery(5f));
}
private IEnumerator ShootEvery(float seconds) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    Shoot();
    StartCoroutine(ShootEvery(seconds));
}
```

*yield return null*

```cs
private void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(ShootEvery(5f));
}
private IEnumerator ShootEvery(float seconds) {
    float dt = 0;
    while(dt < seconds) {
        yield return null;
        dt += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    Shoot();
    StartCoroutine(ShootEvery(5f));
}
```

Thanks for answers

Comment: @BugFinder I used all those different ways to delay/repeat every seconds code, I just don't really know how to test their impact on performances

Comment: In update, the code is executed each frame, which mean in one second there is 40 frame it will be executed 40 times. Coroutine is different because you can determine when you will stop, or begin. You can use while and yield to perform a work that last maybe 1,2 seconds

Comment: All your examples look like you would also want to throw [`InvikeRepeating`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) in the options pool :D